# Laravel page visibility from database solution

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I was wondering if anyone can provide any wisdom of how to accomplish page visibility within my app?  In the database I am storing `visiblity` which is either `"public"` or `"private"`

So, if the page is private, the user would need to be logged in to see the page, but if the page is public, then anyone can view the page.  Below are snippets of my route and controller.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/{slug}', '\App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendPagesController@page');
```

**Page method in FrontendPagesController**

```
public function page($slug){
    $page = Page::where('slug',$slug)->where('active',1)->get()->first();
    if(is_null($page)){
        return abort(404);
    }
    $this->data['page'] = $page;
    return view('pages.page',$this->data);
}
```

The route currently isn't using any middleware.  My first thought was to assign it a middleware that would query the database when it hits this route (to force authentication if it was private), but I didn't want to query the database twice.  Is there a way to pass the results of this said middleware to the controller, or does anyone have any other suggestion on how to accomplish this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but I query the page in the middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $page = Page::where('slug',$request->segment(1))->where('active',1)->get()->first();
    if(is_null($page)){
        return abort(404);
    }
    if($page->visibility === 'private' && !Auth::check()){
        return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
    }
    $request->attributes->add(['page_model' => $page]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Since I added the page to the request, I don't have to query the database more than once.  So now in my controller I can do the following.

```
$request->get('page_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use laravel's local query scope.

in Page Model

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

In your controller

```
public function page($slug){
    $page = Page::active()->where('slug',$slug)->first();

    if( ! $page) {
         // redirect to login page.
    }

    // serve page content.
}
```

You can also use ACL if you need to. 
But remember to **keep it simple.**

Comment: Knowing whether a page is `active` isn't relevant to the question.  Also, since I am not reusing the active query, I don't see why a scope would help